# Art style & how to do it in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, uv, node-editor

So I’ve been working with blender cycles a bit & I have very limited knowledge of how to do different styles. I was wondering if anyone could help me out in any way.
(Note: I do not own these pictures I just want to learn how to do the sketch looking style in 3d models.)

[image]
[image]
[image]
First post so sorry if I’m not very clear.

This is what I’m hoping my renders will look like when I figure out how.
[image]

All help appreciated.

Comment: Cycles is a physically based render, whith a main focus of producing photo realistic imagery. While similar results could probably be achieved it is likely a waste of resources and effort

Comment: Search for Blender NPR. There are several useful resources and also you can build alpha version of Blender 2.8 NPR branch to test whats coming in near future.

Comment: @cgslav.. is there a link for that? I'm not very good at finding my way around the builds.. I wasn't aware of an NPR Branch

Comment: @RobinBetts of course there is: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/history/soc-2018-npr/ and if you want to check other branches you can look here: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/branches/master/ I didn't test it though as I'm not interested in NPR style so I can't give a word for usability of this branch. Pablo made a video about it as far as I remember. Blender Today or Developers channel.